# How to embed a filter in the other side of a foreign key relationship in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following structure:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    doors: BaseManager

class Door(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    room = models.ForeignKey(to=Room, related_name='doors'
)
```

Now after I've saved a room and saved some doors which reference that room I can load a room and get all the doors in the room...

However, when I do a room.doors.all() I actually want to receive only those doors that are not deleted (that have deleted as false).

How would you do this with django?

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I wasn't quite clear in terms of what I wanted...

I want this behaviour: Once I have an instance of room and I go fetch the doors linked to that room with room.doors.all() - at this point I only want doors that are not deleted.

Comment: Rather than calling the all() method.  Call the filter method: room.doors.filter(deleted=False)

Comment: yes, I know I can do that - I don't want that. I don't want the user to have to know that they need to care about deleted. I want them to just do a room.doors.all()

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you want, but room.doors.all().filter(deleted=False) == room.doors.filter(deleted=False). for door in room.doors.filter(deleted=False),  should just provide the not deleted doors for that room.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your `Door` model first:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('deleted', 'deleted'),
        ('not_deleted', 'not_deleted'),
    )
```

Then, edit your `deleted` model field to this:

```
deleted = models.CharField(max_length=1o,choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Then, you can access the doors that are not deleted with:

```
Door.not_deleted.all()
```